# Is it safe to delete ~/Library/Caches?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, file

Is it safe to delete the file Caches, in the Library of the Mac OS X Hard Drive?

It's a pretty big file, 3.56 GB, Caches reminds me of logs i don't need or browser cookies.

Is it safe to delete the folder "Caches"?[image]

Comment: Which folders have the most space? Command-J in list view lets you add up space per folder and sort. You only might need to clear a few and not slow down the programs that use the caches.

Comment: Take a look at `ncdu`.

Comment: https://github.com/danass/Mac-Library-Caches-Cleaner/blob/main/empty_caches.sh to automate removal

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It's generally safe, though a little dangerous depending, to do it but often not worth the effort.

The caches in `/System/Library/Caches` are generally small and useful, the ones in `/Library/Caches` are less system caches and much more readily cleared.

If you have a look in `~/Library/Caches` you will find a bunch of applications have a cache in there, none of them particularly large though dropbox sometimes has a fair sized cache. This folder can run quite large just because so many apps cache something in there.

If the cache `/Library/Caches` folder is over 3Gb then you have something that is caching quite a lot. On the three machines I just checked none had a `/Library/Caches` folder over .75 Gb so I'd go right ahead and remove some of it.

Don't worry about age, I'd worry about size.

In the terminal run the following to sort all of the files in that directory by size (ascending):

```sh
du -sh /Library/Caches/* | sort -h
```

Of course the best way to clear the caches is to install [AppleJack](http://applejack.sourceforge.net/) and do it with that in single user mode. Doing it with the System fully up can be a little dangerous. If you do it then I'd reboot immediately afterwards.

Comment: Note that "sort -n" doesn't play well with the "human readable" option (-h) in du. See for example, http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

Comment: I recommend that instead of using `-h` you use `-m`—it's much easier to read while still working with sort

Comment: Or ``brew install coreutils`` and use ``gsort -h`` instead of ``sort -n`` :)

Comment: In macOS, it is now simple to graphically determine which files/folders are the largest using the System Information app. After opening the app, go to Window > Storage Management, then navigate in the left column to Documents, and then select the tab that says File Browser. This will show your entire user folder's contents sorted by largest file size.

Comment: @jsejcksn Not really, it just groups everything under "System".

Comment: find "/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Caches" -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf {}/* \;

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it is safe. That said, don't just delete all the contents of your cache folder without reason.

It can be beneficial to clear out those taking up the significant space in your `~/Library/Caches/` if you need to free some up, but you really shouldn't clear any contents of your `/System/Caches` unless there is a problem. As would be expected, you will find that the programs you access most often have the largest cache size.

There's a misconception that purging your caches regularly constitutes "maintenance," optimization, etc of your machine, but that's a fallacy; **Always remember that caches improve the performance of your machine**, and shouldn't be cleaned out regularly or blindly without a specific reason.

**Really, the only two reasons to clear out a cache are 1) space considerations (it’s simply growing too large) or 2) You're troubleshooting a problem.**

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is safe *to delete the contents of that folder*.

I usually reboot right after just to be sure but that is temporary file storage and the contents (**not** the folder itself) can be deleted safely

Answer (score 9):

Have no fear, delete caches but I prefer to do it either via Single-User mode or I use https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html Check Onyx out as it does some good maintenance scripts as well.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. However you may want to look inside the folder and selectively delete *old* caches rather then just dumping the whole folder.

Answer (score 4):

I would not blindly delete all.

If you want to do a safe clean up, use the browser tools for history and cookie clean up.

My cache folder is 3.7 gig, and it does contains some important files, so I would not mess with it.

For Safari use the Reset Safari function and select your choices.

[image]

FYI, in my case the app Garmin (European GPS maps) was using >2gig in cache.
Once I was done with it, I deleted it and now back to .7 gig.
In summary, cleaning cache is usually best done by using the respective browser's tools, to delete all the junk accumulated from the web. If you delete something important by mistake that way, well go on the web and get it again.