# App Store on OS X broken after system restoration from backup

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, bug

I recently had to restore my installation of OS X 10.9.4 from a backup. Since then(*), the App Store application is broken. It displays an empty window showing the MAS symbol and the menu bar. Clicking icons in the menu bar highlights them all. Nothing else happens. See the console output below:

> 01.10.14 19:09:08,079 storeagent[759]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c63425c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8cdb1e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c52f22e -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 1102
>       3   storeagent                          0x000000010e751b0b storeagent + 31499
>       4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff904df1bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
>       5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff904dc28d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff904de673 _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
>       7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff904df9c1 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
>       8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff904ddf87 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
>       9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff904df177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
>       10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff96e9bef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
>       11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff96e9efb9 start_wqthread + 13
>   )
>   01.10.14 19:09:08,519 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[163]: (com.apple.storeagent[759]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6

Enabling the debug menu (terminal: *`defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true`*) and resetting the application had not effect (same console output as mentioned above).

I installed OS X 10.9.5 using the terminal. **The Mac App Store application worked until the next reboot**.

What can I do short of reinstalling OS X from the recovery partition?

Comment: Have you tried running either of the Combo updaters? 10.9.4 - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1755?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US  & 10.9.5 - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for reminding me. I installed them both without benefit.

Comment: Recovery [Cmd/R] at boot ?

Comment: @Tetsujin It does not work.

Comment: Didn't go into recovery or didn't fix it?

Comment: @Tetsujin I could not boot in recovery mode.

Comment: Souds like the Recovery partition might be damaged too, then. Maybe try from USB - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433?viewlocale=en_US [Edit... ermm... though you need to find a machine with an intact recovery partition to start with]

Comment: Did you delete the com.apple.storeagent.plist
com.apple.appstore.plist and restarted.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes, it had no result.

Comment: What app do you have running that would overwrite it (setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'), since it worked after install of OS, but would fail after restart. MacKeeper or others ?

Comment: Turn OFF the WiFi and any network connections you might have and start the app store again. It should come up and say "Can not Connect..."

Comment: Try to login as a different user and try use the store on that account. This might give us some information on what is broken.

Comment: @Buscar웃 What else could it be, LaunchBar? Turning off network connections does not help.

Comment: @CousinCocaine The main window shows no content and I can't access the Store menu. A spinning wheel is all I get.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Where can I find this folder? It is in neither in user cache folder nor the system cache folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Options you could try in order to identify the source of your troubles:

- create a new User and try to access the AppStore with your current ID (or a temporary one). If it works, the Problem lies within your User-Profile and not the OS. If it doesn't, the Problem is located in the OS (or the Drive itself).
- OS & User-Profile: try clearing out the Cache files, either manually (see f.e. [StackExchange Article here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118941/is-it-safe-to-delete-library-caches)) or use the freeware '[Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)' (my preferred method)
- OS: Check the Harddrive and the File System Permissions with `Disk Utilities.app` (found in /Applications/Utilities). It is possible (but not liklely) that your HD or Filesystem is defective/corrupt.
- User-Profile: go to `~/Library/Containers/` an move the Folder `com.apple.appstore` somewhere else, f.e. the Desktop. Try starting the App Store again.

Try these and if it doesn't work look in the console. perheaps there are news error messages there.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot to the Recovery HD or internet recovery and install OS X to a usb drive. Then download and install Yosemite.

You are really in the same situation as this user, hence the identical answer I have posted here:

- [How do I install OS X Yosemite without a working Mac App Store application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150876/how-do-i-install-os-x-yosemite-without-a-working-mac-app-store-application)

Comment: it _is_ the same user ;-)

Comment: This question has a focus on how to solve a MAS problem, independently from updating the OS.