# Is it safe to delete Microsoft-"Clones" from Library/Caches?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ms-office, file

I tried to clean up my mac and get back storage.

I tripped over a 1,98GB Folder in the Caches Folder containing a Microsoft Excel Application.
its in /Library/Caches/com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper/clones

I've got two questions:

- Is it safe to delete it, or will it affect my Microsoft excel?
- Why is an application stored in Caches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Is it safe to delete it,

As per Library folder traditions, `Caches` folder should be safe to delete since they serve the secondary purpose of making something faster/ cheaper. Persistent data is in Application Support etc.

- [Is it safe to delete ~/Library/Caches?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118941/is-it-safe-to-delete-library-caches?rq=1)

> - or will it affect my Microsoft excel?

Depends on how the developer intended. So technically only MS can answer that. But if I were short on space, I'd delete it.

- Why is an application stored in Caches?

(not a user so grain of salt) Perhaps a cached download for some scheduled update, to be deleted after update is done.